# A heavenly puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, rebus

If you manage to figure out the solving method to this puzzle below, then it should lead you to a 7-letter word.

---

[image]

---

Hint1:

> [image]

Good luck!

Comment: Is it cutting/copying?

Comment: I believe the CW in the first one referes to a "clockwise turn"...  what ever that might be. Also it's possible that the pie charts refer to 2 turns, 6 turns and 12 turns. Previously thought the lines in the second refers to words insidee the blocks, but theres only two vowels in the 2nd block so that not possible. Finally I also noticed that there are exactly 27 squares in the last one, the same as original.

Comment: Guys, added a hint regarding the first part. @Ankit Hopefully it'll make more sense now

Comment: I have the "final message" but am unsure what the last 4 letters mean or if we actually have to somehow solve the "equation". :) Anything more to it?

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot we have to find a 7-letter word. So I am indeed stuck at the last hurdle again

Comment: @LukasRotter Nice :) If you made it that far, and I'm sure you have since you're mentioning "equation", I can tell you the last "term" is actually *one* misspelled word, on purpose, so that it would fit the puzzle. It's just an extra letter I added and doesn't affect the puzzle. rot13(Gur zrffntr vf npghnyyl n e---f, urapr gur +'f)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:

> **Polaris**

**Transition 1:**

> Assuming the CW stands for *clockwise*, as mentioned by @Ankit, and inferring that the three pies indicate rotations of **180°**, **60°** and **30°** respectively, the second image so formed is as follows: 
> [image]

**Transition 2:**
All credit goes to @LukasRotter for this step. He deciphered how the letters need to be placed for the transition into the third image. In his own words:

> *Which letter to insert is indicated by the position of the square. Example for the red group in the first line: The first two squares have the same Y value, the third is higher than the second, and the last one is higher than the third. Looking at the "solved" second image, we can see that this means they have to be inserted in the order `IEPS`.* 
> [image] 
> Doing this for every square gives us the text **`shiniestplusbearpluspetitte`**, a rebus.

**Final Interpretation:**

> Again, credit to @LukasRotter for pointing out that the answer had to be something *heavenly* and hence outer-space themed. 
> **Shiniest:** Brightest (maybe a star?) 
> **Bear**:  Little Bear/Great Bear constellation? 
> **Petite**: Small/Little/Minor 
> Putting all of this together, I realised it has to be the **brightest** star in the **Little Bear** Constellation, and voila!

Comment: I added a step in my answer, any thoughts where to go from here?

Comment: I got a different answer but yours makes sense as well. The only thing that doesn't make sense is the double t.

Comment: The OP already addressed that in the comments on the question: *I can tell you the last "term" is actually one misspelled word, on purpose, so that it would fit the puzzle. It's just an extra letter I added and doesn't affect the puzzle.*

Comment: Ahhh ok, yep looks like you got it. Well done!

Comment: Well done! And, as expected, I facepalmed because of my inability to connect the dots, lol.

Comment: Yes, it is surprising. I think you'd figured out pretty much everything and surprisingly faltered at the absolute last step, which to me seemed the easiest of the lot.

Comment: Great job to all of you guys! @Kabir, since this is indeed the final 7-letter answer I was looking for you get the tick :)

Comment: Thanks, and great puzzle, btw!

Answer (score 2):

Very good puzzle @Prim3numbah

Picture 1 to 2:

> As attributed to in my comment, @KabirKanhaArora 's answer and the hint, the first clue is that you rotate each block clockwise half a turn, 1/6 turn or 1/12 turn respectfully. This allows us to put the blocks in the second picture surounding the triangle. Check Kabir's fantastic image to see this.

Picture 2 to 3:

> looking at the 3rd image shows three rows: one of 12 squares, 6 squares and 9 squares (aka 4*3, 2*3, 3*3). A looking at the 2nd image shows that each block has a polyline going through 4 letters, 3 letters and 2 letters. Noting the orientation also shows an even spread of half turned, 6th turned, and 12th turned boxes. So they probably correspond in this way. On the note of orientation of boxes, they probably indicate the original block, and the lines in image two shows the order in which they should be input. I'm not sure which direction the blocks lines go in, so I will  label the blocks. We are left with 321231231231 / 123123 / 112312323

Picture 3 to Rebus (in progress)

> First of all, there are 2^9 ways to insert the letters by which side of each line is the start and which is the finish. Also, to pick out 7 letters, I noticed that there are 7 occurances of "123" listed above. I also tried making it "translations of 123" and selecting the ones that don't fit, but that leaves us with 6 letters not 7.

Rebus

> However @LukasRotter gave a very helpful comment that states that if oriented properly I can get it to say shiniestplus/ bearpl / uspetitte. Not 100% sure where to go from here.

Ok I think I may have an answer: (Update: it looks like Kabir got the right answer, mine is different.)

> Bear + Petitte combined with the heavenly clue makes me think of a brown dwarf star (a star with the mass of 15-80 Jupiters). Stars shine... the Shiniest dwarf star is Sagittae. This is 8 letters :(. But note that there is an extra t in the word petite. Does this mean  the answer is "Sagitae"?

Comment: rot13([Vzntr bs tebhcvatf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N24lCm.png). Juvpu yrggre gb vafreg vf vaqvpngrq ol gur cbfvgvba bs gur fdhner. Rknzcyr sbe gur erq tebhc va gur svefg yvar: Gur svefg gjb fdhnerf unir gur fnzr L inyhr, gur guveq vf uvture guna gur frpbaq, naq gur ynfg bar vf uvture guna gur guveq. Ybbxvat ng gur "fbyirq" frpbaq vzntr, jr pna frr gung guvf zrnaf gurl unir gb or vafregrq va gur beqre VRCF. Qbvat guvf sbe rirel fdhner tvirf hf gur grkg fuvavrfgcyhfornecyhfcrgvggr, n erohf)

Comment: Oh, that's neat!

Comment: @LukasRotter Thanks, that is useful!

Comment: Np :) And that's where I gave up. A "heavenly" puzzle suggest an answer themed around outer-space for me, but nothing really made sense. If "shiniest" can loosely be interpreted as "brightest" it might clue SUN or Sirius and petite may just clue S (Small size), but no words matching that criteria made sense and I have no idea what short sequence of letters you could even clue with the word bear. Common 7-letter planets/stars also didn't seem to yield anything useful.

Comment: Ohh, I think I got it. @LukasRotter, you mentioned Bear and celestial objects, so it clicked

Comment: @LukasRotter I got an answer as well, although it is different. Kabir' s answer also makes sense but it the double t "petitte" doesn't make sense.